# jQuery keyboard Input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a video game and I would like to know how to get keyboardInput and I really like the jQuery input so I would be happy if somebody could show me how it works. I already searched in the internet for my problem but I can't find a solution for it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide some code you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

To get the keyboard input You can use the jquery `.keypress()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the Jquery event like keypress,keydown and keyup.

```
var docu = document.getElementsByTagName('document');
docu.onkeydown = function (event) {  
    if (event.keyCode == 116) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        window.history.go(-1);//return the last page                
    }  
}
```

And keycode is the code for the key....A is related to 65
And this is the keycode table.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmNnu.png)

Comment: $(document).keydown() is a jquery way to code. you can replace onkeydown () as a function